# Erro na execução de function SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, funções

Tenho uma prova de banco de dados hoje e to praticando functions com exercicios antigos só que to recebendo um erro quando executo a função.

tabelas

```
set language brazilian; 
CREATE TABLE pedido (  
nr_pedido numeric(5) NOT NULL,  
dt_pedido date,  
nr_mesa numeric(4)  
);  

CREATE TABLE itens_pedido (  
nr_pedido numeric(5) NOT NULL,  
nr_prod numeric(5) NOT NULL,  
qt_item smallint  
);  

CREATE TABLE produto (  
nr_prod numeric(5) NOT NULL,  
ds_produto varchar(60) NOT NULL,  
vl_venda numeric(9,2)  
);
```

PS.: as chaves primarias e estrangeiras foram definidos com alter table.

inserts

```
insert into produto values(1, 'Velho Barreiro', 5.00),
(2, 'Ypioca', 10.00),
(3, 'Casquinha de Caranguejo', 55.00),
(4, 'Calabresa', 15.00),
(5, 'Feijão Tropeiro', 29.50),
(6, 'Muqueca de camarão', 79.50),
(7, 'Coca-Cola', 9.90),
(8, 'Suco de Laranja', 2.50),
(9, 'Macaxeira', 12.30),
(10, 'Soda Limonada', 2.10),
(11, 'Coração de Galinha', 11.20),
(12, 'Vodka Skarloff', 13.70),
(13, 'Caninha 61', 9.90)

INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (1, GETDATE(), 527),
(2, '10/10/2009', 632),
(3, '21/05/2009', 606),
(4, '26/06/2009', 970),
(5, '05/05/2009', 606),
(6, '13/11/2009', 527),
(7, '01/03/2005', 181),
(8, '09/04/2010', 181);      

INSERT INTO itens_pedido VALUES (1, 11, 2),
(1, 4, 1),
(2, 3, 15),
(3, 2, 2),
(3, 8, 2),
(4, 1, 3),
(4, 7, 2),
(5, 5, 4),
(5, 6, 2),
(6, 6, 3),
(7, 10, 2),
(7, 9, 4),
(2, 2, 5);
```

No exercício tem a seguinte questão:

> 2) Mostre através de uma função o valor total do pedido passado como parâmetro.

então criei a seguinte function:

```
create function ex_f2(@ped numeric(5))
returns numeric(8,2)
as
begin
declare @total numeric(8,2)
set @total = (select pr.vl_venda * i.qt_item
from pedido p inner join itens_pedido i 
on p.nr_pedido = i.nr_pedido inner join produto pr 
on pr.nr_prod = i.nr_prod
where p.nr_pedido = @ped)
return (@total)
end
```

Porém ao executar com o select:

> select dbo.ex_f2(1)

eis que retorna o erro:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 114 
>   A subconsulta retornou mais de 1
>   valor. Isso não é permitido quando a subconsulta segue um =, !=, <, <=
>   , >, >= ou quando ela é usada como uma expressão.

PS2.: Essa é a function que o professor criou na hora de corrigir o exercício(ela da o mesmo erro):

```
create function ex_f2(@pedi numeric(5))
returns numeric(8,2)
as
begin
return (select i.qt_item * pr.vl_venda 'valor total'
from pedido p inner join itens_pedido i on p.nr_pedido = i.nr_pedido
inner join produto pr on pr.nr_prod = i.nr_prod
where p.nr_pedido = @pedi)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

No código da sua função, substitua a linha

```
set @total = (select pr.vl_venda * i.qt_item
```

por

```
set @total = (select sum(pr.vl_venda * i.qt_item)
```

Comment: cara valeu eu tava ficando meio bolado com isso valeu mesmo.